# Encoding problems when certain characters are excluded with translate (Python)

Tags: python-2.7, utf-8, character-encoding

I am working on a script that creates a word frequency distribution list.
I strip special characters using translate. It works great, even with symbols as french quotation marks **«** or **»**. But as soon as I add **…** or **–** to the list of excluded symbols, the resulting list changes the display of words like

> wie's:1

to

> wie<99>s:1

Source document encoding is utf-8.

Here is a shortened working example of my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

inputfile = "articel.txt"
outputfile = "articel_dic.txt"
myoutput = open(outputfile, "w")
dic = {}
myinput = open(inputfile, "r").readlines()

for line in myinput:
    words = line.split()
    for word in words:
        word = word.translate(None, ",.?-;!:«»…")
        if word in dic:
            dic[word] += 1
        else:
            dic[word] = 1    

outtext = ""
for key in dic:
    outtext += key +":"+ str(dic[key]) +"\n"
s = outtext     
myoutput.write(s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.translate` can break multibyte characters because it is not aware of UTF-8. Specifically, it treats the `deletechars` argument as a string of bytes that are to be deleted individually. Trying to delete « and » has the same problem but it affects different characters; you were just lucky not to have any such characters in your text.

You must work in Unicode:

```
mapping = {ord(x): None for x in u",.?-;!:«»…"}
word = word.decode("utf8").translate(mapping)

myoutput.write(s.encode("utf8"))
```